# If $T$ has irreducible minimal polynomial, can one decompose the space as a direct sum of invariant subspaces without non-trivial invariant subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials, direct-sum, invariant-subspace

$T: W \rightarrow W$ is a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space $W$.
If the minimal polynomial of linear operator $T$ on $W$ is irreducible, is there a way to decompose $W$ into $$W=W_1\oplus W_2\oplus \cdots\oplus W_n$$ where each $W_i$ is a subspace of $W$, and
for each $i$, $W_i$ has no non-trivial $T$-invariant subspaces?
Here non-trivial means neither $\{0\}$ nor $W_i$.

Comment: What is the minimal polynomial of a vector space?

Comment: And which vector spaces have only trivial subspaces?

Comment: Can you specify any assumptions on the $W_i$ and their subspaces?  For instance, you've tagged with "invariant subspace", which would perhaps provide an interesting question relating to the Jordan blocks of an endomorphism on $W$, but you haven't made that explicit.  With no clear assumptions on what type of subspaces you're looking at, this is a rather trivial problem, just amounting to a choice of basis.

Comment: I just edited my question. The assumption on having no non-trivial subspaces is indeed of great significance. I think now it is readable.

Comment: Something is missing here. You write "where $T$ is the linear operator on $W$", but you do not giveany  information **what** $T$ is. Any linear $W \to W$?

Comment: $T$ is any linear transformation, I think.

Comment: The reason everyone is confused is that your question lacks a clear statement of what data you are starting with.

Comment: I edited it again, it is clear enough?

Comment: By "non-trivial subspace of $W_i$" do you mean just not $\{0\}$, or also not $W_i$ itself?

Comment: neither $\{0\}$ nor $W_i$

Comment: Hint: if $p$ is the irreducible minimal polynomial of $T$, and $F$ is the (original) scalar field, then $W$ also becomes a vector space over the field $F[t] / \langle p(t) \rangle$, and minimal invariant subspaces of $W$ over $F$ correspond to one-dimensional subspaces of $W$ over $F[t] / \langle p(t) \rangle$.

Comment: I think the question is still not stated correctly. Any finite-dimensional space can be decomposed into $1$-dimensional subspaces, and a $1$-dimensional space has no non-trivial subspaces. $T$ is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes such a decomposition is always possible. Here are two approaches.

By the structure theorem of finitely generated modules over a PID (here $K[X]$ with $X$ acting as $T$), the space decomposes as a direct sum of modules isomorphic to some $K[X]/P_i$ for non constant monic polynomials $P_1,\ldots,P_k$ where each $P_i$ (with $i<k$) divides $P_{i+1}$. The minimal polynomial (which annihilates the entire module) is the final $P_k$. As it is given that this minimal polynomial is irreducible, so without non-constant proper divisors, all the $P_i$ must equal $P_k$, and this gives your result.

Alternatively, your $K[X]$ module naturally becomes a $K[X]/\mu$ module for the minimal polynomial $\mu$, since $\mu$ acts as $0$ on it. But if $\mu$ is irreducible then $K[X]/\mu$ is a field$~F$, and we are dealing with a vector space over$~F$. As such it has bases (or cardinal $\dim_F(W)=\dim_K(W)/\deg(\mu)$) and each such basis gives a direct sum of $1$-dimensional $F$-subspaces, which gives you a decomposition as a $K$-vector space as described in the question.